# I need to replace all vowels in a string with a ' - ' from a user input

Tags: c#

Instead of an exact answer I am looking for guidance, since this problem is for a homework assignment and I must learn! Anyways, I cannot use the .Replace method but I must replace an vowels with a '-' dash symbol and then output the original input with the dashes back to the user. so far this is what I have but I cannot figure out how to add in the dashes now. also I have to do this inside another method I created which is listed down below.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {





        //problem #2 Redacted Files///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello please provide a short statement we can work with!");
        string normalString = Console.ReadLine();
        while (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(normalString)) 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter in an amount");
            normalString = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        EncryptingMethod(normalString);


    }



    //Problem #2 method///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public static string EncryptingMethod(string normalString)
    {
        //List <char> charVowelList = new List<char>() { 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y','A','E','I','O','U','Y'};
        char[] normalCharArray = normalString.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < normalCharArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (normalCharArray[i] == 'a' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'e' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'i' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'o' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'u' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'y' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'A' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'E' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'I' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'O' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'U' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'Y')
            {
                char[] normalEncryptArray = normalCharArray.Insert('-', normalCharArray[i]);
            }
        }


        return normalString;
    }
}
```

}
 The .Insert I have at the bottom will not work, it wont even run with that code but so far its one of the many formats I have tried.

Comment: Offtopic: replace your big if with `"aeiouyAEIOUY".Contains(normalCharArray[i])`.

Comment: Thank you. It will be way easier to work with in that format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done a lot of good things yourself. To understand why your code doesn't work, look at following line.

```
char[] normalEncryptArray = normalCharArray.Insert('-', normalCharArray[i]);
```

A char array doesn't have an Insert Method. What you need to do here is replace existing character, you need to modify it as following.

```
normalCharArray[i] = '-';
```

The second change you require in the method is final return statement.

```
return normalString;
```

Remember, all your changes are now in the char array normalCharArray. So that's the one you need to return. Since the expected return value is a string, you need to convert the array to a string. You can do so using the constructor of string class.

```
 return new string(normalCharArray);
```

Your whole method would look like following now.

```
 public static string EncryptingMethod(string normalString)
    {
        char[] normalCharArray = normalString.ToCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < normalCharArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (normalCharArray[i] == 'a' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'e' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'i' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'o' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'u' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'y' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'A' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'E' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'I' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'O' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'U' ||
                normalCharArray[i] == 'Y')
            {
                normalCharArray[i] = '-';
            }
        }


        return new string(normalCharArray);
    }
```

Btw, you can make couple of improvements here. For example,

The entire if condition can be improved by following line

```
if ("aeiouyAEIOUY".Contains(normalCharArray[i])) 
{
  normalCharArray[i] = '-';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Ive been up all night working with these assigments and its hard to even think straight anymore. now I can finish up and reflect on these answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace characters in the orignial `char[]` array directly:

```
normalCharArray[i] = '-';
```

---

Also, as suggested in the comments, you can simplify the big `if` with the `string.Contains` method which checks, whether the string contains a given character.

```
char[] normalCharArray = normalString.ToCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < normalCharArray.Length; i++)
    if ("aeiouyAEIOUY".Contains(normalCharArray[i]))
        normalCharArray[i] = '-';

return new string(normalCharArray);
```

Comment: Man I seem to really be over thinking these problems. Your input is extremely appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Regex, if it's not to be specifically excluded from your assignment:

```
        //Problem #2 method///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        public static string EncryptingMethod(string normalString)
        {
            string vowels = "[aeiouyAEIOUY]"; //sets the letters you need to replace
            string replacement = "-";//what to replace the vowels with

            Regex rep = new Regex(vowels); //initiate the Regex

            string updatedString = rep.Replace(normalString, replacement); //rep will now look up for each character in VOWELS and update it with REPLACEMENT

            return updatedString;
        }
```

Comment: unfortunately for this one it was, from all my research I could tell that its definitely the way to go though.